# Cost effective electronic packaging solution

Tags: electrical-engineering

What would be a cost effective environmentally friendly material to package a simple electronic circuit? The electronic circuit consist of active and passive devices. These electronic circuit also need to be protected from moisture through the duration of use, which could more then 5 years. The system will have a IP rated connector to provide power and support data communication. The product will be 60 x 40 x 20 mm in size.

The choices presented are PVC or ABS+PC for the outer shell. Potting material will be dispensed inside the enclosure protect from water or moisture seepage.

Are the above cost effective environmentally friendly solutions? If so why, if not what are other available options.

---

**Reference:**

- [A guide to the plastics used for Electronic Enclosures](https://www.okwenclosures.com/en/technical_data/enclosures_plastics_guide.html)
- [Custom Potting Compounds](https://www.keypolymer.com/potting-encapsulating/specialty/)

Comment: Note: There are plethora recommendations from vendors, input from practitioners would be welcome.

Comment: If it's potted, it will be impractical to recycle when it reaches end-of-life. There is some industry effort to reduce halogenated plastics like PVC, driven by fire-safety (fumes if burned) and to a perhaps lesser extent by environmental reasons. Commodity plastics that can be recycled are nice (e.g. HDPE,PP,PET) but have compromises. PBT is an excellent higher-end plastic shell material (keyboard keys, under-the-hood car electrical).

Comment: oh and Nylon is another common low cost option for small shells.

Comment: PVC is not environmentally friendly. Steel or aluminum is probably more environmentally friendly than any plastic.  If it is being potted does it even need such a durable non-biodegradeable shell to begin with? That's just more waste. Is this one-off or mass production? Little disposable aluminum foil containers for kitchen use exist which you can pot in.

Comment: @DKNguyen, This is for Mass Production. Current thought is to dispense potting to top of the casing, near and around the lid. Expect life of the product is 10 years. Thank you for your idea. I think we could do better.

Comment: How do you justify any plastic as environmentally friendly?

Comment: @SolarMike, exactly the point. Do you have alternate suggestion?

Comment: in my experience, packaging is the stuff you put products in to ship or sell them.  You're talking about an enclosure.

Comment: There are plastics (celluloid, bakelite) made from renewable organic materials.  Certainly no one would claim steel or aluminum to be environmentally friendly due to the energy used in manufacture.  For this question to be answerable, we need a better specification than "environmentally friendly."

Comment: @TigerGuy, The question is focused on protecting passive and active electronic circuits from environment conditions such as moisture, dust etc.

Comment: @TigerGuy well with advent of carbon free aluminium production they are pretty ecological. I mean places like Norway have surplus green energy to spare.